# Google Sheets equivalent of Sort a Tranpose but for Excel? or alternative?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, transpose

I'm converting some google sheets files to Excel (2019 Mac) and one of the formulas I cant seem to replicate is

```
=SORT(transpose({'Part 1'!E2:GEV2}))
```

Seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXumS.jpg). The goal is to combine all the entries in a row on another sheet then only display entries (no 0's between the gaps). Perhaps there is something I'm missing. I've tried

```
=TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!E2:T2)
```

but that displays a bunch of 0's on the cells that don't contain data and doesn't sort the data to only give me the important stuff at the top.

Comment: I don't have the newest version of Excel so don't have the Sort and Filter functions. Can't upgrade my system either.

Comment: What kind of data is in `E2:T2`?  And it is not clear to me what you want for output. A screenshot of your data and desired output would be much more useful than the screenshot of the formula you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transpose and eliminate the blanks, you can try:

```
=TRIM(MID(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",999),TRUE,E2:T2),IF(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,255))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,255))-1)*999),999))
```

Not sure how you'll SORT the results, though, without the function, unless you write your own UDF.

[image]

Comment: Yes this is what I want to do! upon more reading the goal isn't to sort the results just eliminate blanks which I assumed I would need to sort but I was wrong about that. This is correct!

Comment: I'm encountering an error with this formula. If I scan too many cells (seems to be more than 33 results) It gives me #VALUE! error. Do I need to alter something to have more than 33 results?

Comment: You've run into the `2^15` character number limitation. Change the `999` to `99`. So long as the individual entries are not too long, it should work for up to a few hundred results.  If you have larger numbers of cells, you could either write a UDF, or use a Windows version with the `FILTERXML` function.